# Unable to get steps on flutter app properly with google fit api

Tags: android, flutter, google-fit, android-14

We are developing an application on flutter and using google fit api on it. App needs physical activity permission on devices but it doesn't work properly on android 14 version (OneUI 6.0) at Samsung S23 Ultra, and works with Samsung Note 9 well. It doesn't count steps when we switch widgets on our app screen. How can we solve this issue?

Sincerely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to share with you the email response that the Google Fit Development team wrote to me as follows.

> The [Fit Android API](https://developers.google.com/fit/android) has already been deprecated and will be shut
> down by 2024; therefore, we strongly suggest migrating from Fit to
> Health Connect. Refer to the [Migration Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/health-and-fitness/health-connect-guidelines/migrate/migration-guide) for instructions on
> Health Connect migration.
>
> As the API has been deprecated since May 2022, updates, code changes,
> and documentation support have ceased as well and with the most recent
> OS releases and updates, it is probable that the library will exhibit
> irregular behavior.
>
> Best regards